# Where to look up numerical information of finite groups of small orders (<2047)?

Tags: finite-groups

I need some information of finite groups of order (<2047) for my thesis project, such as the number of their normal subgroups, the composition length and composition series. And I also need to carry out some numerical experiments, for example finding the group with the longest composition series or with the most (normal) subgroups. Some friends told me that I can do these with the help of the programming (magma), but I want to know whether there's any authoritative handbook on these facts.

Can any expert or veteran give me some suggestions? thank u so much!

Comment: If you do not have GAP , I only know two online tools : magma online calculator (with a handbook how to use it also online) or WIMS - permutation groups, which has limited access to the small groups (but only upto order 255)

Comment: [This](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Shaun@Peter thanks a lot!